# Contact Form 7 не работает счетчик Яндекса

Tags: contact-form7

Использую плагин Contact Form 7.

В нем есть вкладка "дополнительные настройки". Раньше вставлял туда цель Метрики:

```
on_sent_ok:"yaCounterХХХХХХХХ.reachGoal(‘submit’);"
```

Сейчас плагин рекомендует on_sent_ok заменить событием wpcf7mailsent. Вставил вместо on_sent_ok:

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  yaCounterXXXXXXX.reachGoal('zzzzz');
}, false );
```

Также в файлы function.php в главной и дочерней теме добавил в конец:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    yaCounterXXXXXXX.reachGoal('zzzzz');
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

При отправке формы около кнопки вращается значок загрузки. Надписи о успешной отправке нет. Хотя имею такое в коде страницы:

```
{into: "#wpcf7-f3535-p2612-o1", status: "mail_sent",…}
into
:
"#wpcf7-f3535-p2612-o1"
message
:
"Спасибо за Ваше сообщение. Оно успешно отправлено."
status
:
"mail_sent"
```

На почту заявка приходит. В метрике счетчик достижения цели не работает...

Вы писали в похожем вопросе "(Для метрики нужно заменить js-скрипт)". Поясните этот момент, пожалуйста.

Может еще в этом проблема. До этого стояла старая версия CF7, удалял, ставил новую. Потом удалил и старую версию, методом копирования папки плагина установил, активировал. Потом опять удалял, но когда идет удаление, то статус удаление висит бесконечно долго. Пока не обновишь страницу. Может это как-то влиять?

Заранее благодарен за помощь...